# Streaming Audio from video server c#

Tags: c#, streaming, rtsp, rtp

I have a video server with an IP:192.168.1.XX
It has 3 possible formats JPEG, MPEG-4 or H.264

The video server is broadcasting a video(with audio) on real time

I have no problems streaming the video with AFORGE lib
but i also need to stream the audio

the video server has several protocols: HTTP,RTSP,RTP,RTCP

according to the user's manual RTSP is the protocol I should use to get MPEG-4(Audio and video), but I haven't found anything to stream by RTSP on C# so I'm trying to stream audio and video separate

the ports are:

RTSP: 554
RTP(Video): 5556
RTP(Audio):5558
RTCP(Video): 5557
RTCP(Audio): 5559

Does any body know how RTP works or how can I get the sound from the video server?

Answer (score 1):

I would learn gstreamer. I am assuming that you are using windows since you are doing this in C#. It has a fairly stable windows port with a nice .net wrapper. If you aren't using Windows, then gstreamer is most certainly your best bet.

In gstreamer you would most likely use a pipeline like:

```
your video src -> x264enc or ffenc_mpv4 -> rtph264pay or rtpmp4vpay -> udpsink

your audio src  -> ffenc_aac or preferably a lower latency codec like mULaw -> rtppay -> udpsink
```

and so on. It is very easy to use. They even have a nice rtpbin for your to use if you want to actually manage an rtp session.

More information can be found here:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Here is a nice sample of how to do rtp:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-gstrtpbin.html

I have done this sort of thing with the direct show filters but it is much more involved. You usually have to manually handle the rtp payloading and the transport--not to mention deal with COM--whereas GStreamer provides those mechanisms for you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://net7mma.codeplex.com/

It is a C# Media Server and it will get you each RtpPacket and from there you can get them to a Decoder of your choice among other things all without bogging down the source stream.